# r correlation matrix long format

Tags: r, dplyr, correlation

This may be the millionth question on estimating the correlation matrix in R, my apologies , I was unable to find an answer to my question.

I am trying to estimate the correlation in **weight** between **different pigs** (4601, 4602, etc)

Here's my dataset

```
library("geepack")
data(dietox)
df <- dietox[, c("Weight", "Pig")]
head(df)

 Weight  Pig
67.00000 4601
76.59998 4601
86.50000 4601
91.59998 4601
98.59998 4601
30.09999 4602
38.29999 4602
44.50000 4602
.        .
.        .
.        .
```

This is my code

```
df %>%
group_by(Pig) %>%
cor()
```

I am getting an error , `Error in cor(.) : 'x' must be numeric`, any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The `cor` on the single column will give only 1

Comment: @akrun, how do I then, get correlation between weights for different IDs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, we need to reshape to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
    mutate(rn = rowid(Pig)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = Weight) %>% 
    column_to_rownames("Pig") %>% 
    as.matrix %>%
    cor
```

-output

```
       1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11 12
1  1.0000000 0.9222855 0.9089571 0.8672937 0.8135320 0.7363923 0.7408283 0.7516862 0.7175035 0.6834182 0.7003925 NA
2  0.9222855 1.0000000 0.9558717 0.9157019 0.8600880 0.7859677 0.7955397 0.7830242 0.7404776 0.6852512 0.6953134 NA
3  0.9089571 0.9558717 1.0000000 0.9515235 0.8965352 0.8293146 0.8136445 0.7945452 0.7745692 0.7195725 0.7247124 NA
4  0.8672937 0.9157019 0.9515235 1.0000000 0.9577877 0.9188810 0.8950779 0.8803371 0.8581694 0.8064507 0.8104515 NA
5  0.8135320 0.8600880 0.8965352 0.9577877 1.0000000 0.9665819 0.9369499 0.9139555 0.8983066 0.8185975 0.8337903 NA
6  0.7363923 0.7859677 0.8293146 0.9188810 0.9665819 1.0000000 0.9568397 0.9327316 0.9280462 0.8538419 0.8557321 NA
7  0.7408283 0.7955397 0.8136445 0.8950779 0.9369499 0.9568397 1.0000000 0.9688745 0.9556239 0.8860879 0.8914012 NA
8  0.7516862 0.7830242 0.7945452 0.8803371 0.9139555 0.9327316 0.9688745 1.0000000 0.9657392 0.8894930 0.8929204 NA
9  0.7175035 0.7404776 0.7745692 0.8581694 0.8983066 0.9280462 0.9556239 0.9657392 1.0000000 0.9192849 0.9352723 NA
10 0.6834182 0.6852512 0.7195725 0.8064507 0.8185975 0.8538419 0.8860879 0.8894930 0.9192849 1.0000000 0.9358353 NA
11 0.7003925 0.6953134 0.7247124 0.8104515 0.8337903 0.8557321 0.8914012 0.8929204 0.9352723 0.9358353 1.0000000 NA
12        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  1
```

---

Or if it should be with ID

```
out <- df %>% 
   mutate(rn = rowid(Pig)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = Pig, values_from = Weight) %>% 
   column_to_rownames("rn") %>%
    as.matrix %>%
    cor
 dim(out)
[1] 72 72
```